# Install Google Chrome Ubuntu 12.04 without sudo

Tags: google-chrome

I was wondering if I could install google chrome without using the `sudo` command.

I've tried to use the tutorials from google but I couldn't read it because I accidently downloaded the french version of Ubuntu, so I basically don't know what's happening, also, I'm a complete noob at Ubuntu... so if anyone could give me a very very basic tutorial on how to do it, it would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would one find this advantages?

Comment: Why not this one? http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-change-linux-language/

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8926/installing-chrome-on-linux-without-needing-to-be-root

Comment: it is an advantage on a network in which you have space but not admin privileges. @TheXed

Answer (score 5):

**1)**

```
cd
mkdir -p ~/local/pkg
mkdir -p ~/local/src/chrome
mkdir -p ~/local/bin
```

**2)** Download [the package](https://www.google.com/intl/en_uk/chrome/browser/) corresponding to your Linux distribution to the `~/local/pkg` directory. If you're on Ubuntu, this is the `.deb` package.

**3)** Extract the package in the `~/local/src/chrome/` directory:

- If `.deb` package: `dpkg -x google-chrom...`
- If `.rpm` package: `rpm2cpio ~/local/pkg/google-chrom... | cpio -id`

**4)** Link libraries:

```
cd ~/local/src/chrome/opt/google/chrome/
ln -s /lib64/libbz2.so.1 libbz2.so.1.0
ln -s /lib64/libnspr4.so libnspr4.so.0d
ln -s /usr/lib64/libnss3.so libnss3.so.1d
ln -s /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so libnssutil3.so.1d
ln -s /lib64/libplc4.so libplc4.so.0d
ln -s /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so libsmime3.so.1d
```

**5)** Add `~/local/bin/` to your path by pasting

```
for dir in "$HOME/local/bin"; do
  if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
    PATH="$dir:$PATH"
  fi
done
```

in your `.bashrc` file, then run `source ~/.bashrc`. Done!

Comment: In Trusty, `ldd chrome` complained about a missing `libudev.so.0` which in fact does not exist on my system. `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1` does, but it seems like this was bumped up from .0 to .1 in Precise. However http://askubuntu.com/a/531098/49860 clarified that you can just make a symlink between them. I also had to add the directory with the symlink to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and make sure `…/opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox` was `-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root`, but then it worked. Workaround for [poor Hangout support in Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=416856).

Comment: Good to know, how did you `chown` the sandbox without sudo access though?

Comment: In my case I _did_ have `sudo` access, I just did not want to install Chrome as a package.

Comment: Best answer here. I like that this isn't just applicable just to chrome

Comment: By the way http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8934/26736 seems very similar.

Answer (score 4):

I guess without `sudo` you cannot install google chrome. Because google chrome will try to install it in directory `/opt` and few other root directory, which needs `sudo` privilege.

But the alternative way is to install the **chrome portable app**. But to run a portable app you must have [RUNZ framework](http://hacktolive.org/files/runz/runz-framework-0.8.9.8.deb)

Follow the procedures in this [link](http://jaxov.com/2009/09/download-portable-google-chrome-for-ubuntu-linux/) to install google chrome portable.

But I would recommend you to install the Google chrome with sudo permissions using the below commands

### Add PPA to

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
```

### Install Google chrome

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

There is no French version of ubuntu, it's just language you chose while installing ubuntu, you can [change it](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/session-language.html) if you wish.

The `sudo` command is for giving administrator privileges for an operation, admin privilege is necessary for installing a software, by the way, why don't you want to use `sudo`?

Comment: This is not an answer, and not true for the second part...

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the stable version of `google-chrome` from the [home page](https://www.google.com/chrome/)
2. Extract the downloaded package to a location of your choice

   `e.g:` with .deb package: `dpkg -x google-chrom... path/to/google-chrome`
3. Run `google-chrome` from `path/to/google-chrome/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome`
4. Follow this step if you wish to open `google-chrome` from your status bar. When `google-chrome` is open right click on the icon at the status bar then select `lock to launcher` option.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the latest builds of the [chromium project](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium) and use it directly without `sudo`. All you would need to do is to extract the `zip` they provide and then execute it using terminal. You can look for more information in this method at [how-to-install-chromium-zip-file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114384/how-to-install-chromium-zip-file)

Comment: Please clarify if you have actually done so *recently*.

Comment: @vasa1 No I havent. Any recent change that blocks this?

Comment: I'm asking mainly because providing an updated Chromium for Ubuntu isn't keeping pace. You may want to check [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/105102/25656).

Comment: @vasa1 that question is talking about `.deb`s right? Is it the same case for `.zip`?

Comment: That's why I asked if you've actually done so. It would be of interest to the community at large.