# How to fix missing libudev.so.0 for Chrome to start again?

Tags: 13.04, 64-bit, 13.10, google-chrome

Trying to start chrome yields in following error on the command line:

```
/opt/google/chrome/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The error first appeared in Ubuntu 13.04, I tried purging and reinstalling Chrome. It persisted after upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If Chrome doesn't start after an Ubuntu upgrade from ≤12.10 to ≥13.04, open a terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure google-chrome-stable
```

Explanations follow.

---

At least for Chrome versions form 28 to 37, the Chrome binary can use whichever of `libudev.so.0` or `libudev.so.1` is present on the system. With the fix to [Chromium/Chrome Issue 226002](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=226002) (which went into the unstable channel in April 2013), the installer determines which one to use. The binary references `libudev.so.0`; the installer creates a symbolic link from `/opt/google/chrome/libudev.so.0` to the `libudev.so.1` on the system if `libudev.so.0` is not found.

Note that it would be a bad idea to create one in `/usr/lib`. Major version numbers in libraries change when the newer version is incompatible. Creating this symbolic link works well for Chrome because it only uses features that are compatible between version 0 and version 1. Other applications might crash or produce corrupt data if you force them to run with the wrong version.

The method used by the Chrome package works well under most circumstances, but it's still a dirty hack, and it has a limitation. If the `libudev0` package is uninstalled after Chrome is installed, which is likely to happen when you upgrade Ubuntu, then Chrome will still be set up to use `libudev.so.0` but the file won't be available anymore. To fix this, cause the installation script to run again, and this time detect that `libudev.so.0` is not available so it should create the symbolic link to use `libudev.so.1` instead. You can re-run the installation script by running `dpkg-reconfigure google-chrome-stable` as root.

Answer (score 36):

As Gilles pointed out, this approach can lead to unwanted behaviour. Please try [his solution first](https://askubuntu.com/a/531098/32792). If it doesn't work for you and you understand the implication that *this may lead to silent data corruption*, you may do the following:

Assuming a 64-bit system, the missing symlink can be created via:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.3.5 /usr/lib/libudev.so.0
```

For Ubuntu 18:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.9 /usr/lib/libudev.so.0
```

For a 32-bit system:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.3.5  /usr/lib/libudev.so.0
```

You may have to check your local version of libudev.

Comment: This answer also applies to issue like "Google Chrome does not start after upgrade to 13.10."

Comment: This also works for Dartium (the development version of Chromium with Dart VM embedded). Although I created the link against the link libudev.so.1  instead in the hope that if the version changes the link still wroks, but I'm not sure about that. The only thing I can said is that it worked for me. Kubuntu 14.10.

Comment: This is a bad idea: it works for Chrome, but it could break other programs that don't come from Ubuntu — instead of getting an error message, you could get silent data corruption.

Comment: This works for me