# How do I restrict the users from installing applications from being installed on the linux machine?

Tags: 14.04, browser, su

How do I restrict the users from installing applications from being installed on the ubuntu linux machine? I have root privileges and there are three users in the ubuntu linux machine. I would like to restrict the users from installing any "web browsers" or specific web browsers from being installed. (These users have sudo access)

Comment: restricted sudo access I hope you mean, since with full sudo access, they can undo anything you can do as root.

Answer (score 0):

If the users have `sudo` privileges, it is almost impossible to restrict them from doing something unless you specify a whitelist of specific commands they **are** allowed to use.

If asking the users not to do something is not good enough, then look at [this SuperUser SE answer](https://superuser.com/a/735286/495061) for other possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Since Google Chrome [can be installed without sudo](https://askubuntu.com/a/455106/395993), there is no reasonable way to prevent users from running it no matter how hard you try. This may apply to other browsers as well.